# Typescript map is not able to return JSX.Element

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, frontend, tsx

I am making a const map in typescript as

```
export const CUSTOM_MAP = {

  'a': 'some text',
  'b': 'some text',
  'c': 'some text',
};
```

I want to extract the values from CUSTOM_MAP on the basis of key matching with some passed value **as below** and return some **JSX.Element** from that function to DOM.

But the below code is not returning the JSX.Element after **if (key === errorStatus)** condition get true.

May be I am not able to return in proper way. **Please let me know how to return the JSX.Element from map() block of functionName()**.

```
// Function which is faulty.

const functionName = (errorStatus: string): JSX.Element => {

  Object.entries(CUSTOM_MAP).map(([key,value]) => {
    if (key === errorStatus) {
      // below code is not able to return from here to where the functionName() is called
      return (            
        <>
          <div>
            Some html code with this {value}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  });
  return <>
  </>;
};

export default errorCasesHandling;
```

Comment: `.map` will loop through everything in the entries and return all of them as an array. To pick only one, use `.filter`, or simply just `CUSTOM_MAP[key]`.

Comment: `<> Some html code with this .{CUSTOM_MAP[errorStatus]} </>`.  is not working in typescript. throwing me some typescript errors

Comment: A handy cheatsheet for the three most common transformation Array methods: `.map` for producing an array of the same length and the same or different values; `.filter` for an array of the same or lesser length consisting of elements that were in your original array; `.reduce` for producing just about anything, based on your original array (including other types entirely). You can also use `.includes` rather than a conditional and `Object.keys`, or `.find` to get the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has some issues:

- first of all the you are trying to return an array of JSX elements, so the type of return values should be JSX.Element[].
- second, you didn't return the result of the map function;
- beside that, I guess you wanted to return <></> if the condition `key === errorStatus` not satisfied but you put it outside of map. so your code will be like:

```
const functionName = (errorStatus: string): JSX.Element[] => {
  return Object.entries(CUSTOM_MAP).map(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === errorStatus) {
      return (            
        <>
          <div>
            Some html code with this {value}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    return <></>;
  });
};
```

at the end if i misunderstood the third item that I said, you can use a filter function before the map;

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for making me understand. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return in front of `Object.entries`. Try the following code:

```
const functionName = (errorStatus: string) => {
  return Object.entries(CUSTOM_MAP).map(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === errorStatus) {
      // below code is not able to return from here to where the functionName() is called
      return (
        <>
          <div>Some html code with this {value}</div>
        </>
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This is throwing me some typescript error

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
const functionName = (errorStatus: string): JSX.Element => {
  let elements: JSX.Element | null = null;
  Object.entries(CUSTOM_MAP).map(([key,value]) => {
    if (key === errorStatus)
    {
      element = (            
       // jsx elements
      );
    }
  });
  return elements || <></>;
};

export default functionName;
```